# Alternative to thunar on Ubuntu Studio 18.10

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager, ubuntu-studio, thunar

I just need a simple file manager which shows not just date of modification, as Thunar does, but date-hour-minute-second.

Comment: This is a very personal choice (which file-manager/any-program best suits your tastes), but PCMan-FM  (from LXDE) provides everything by default *except seconds*.  Lubuntu from 18.10 now runs LX-Qt, so I'm suggesting PCManFM (not Lubuntu's 18.10 new default PCManFm-Qt) which uses GTK+ and should be lighter unless you already have Qt libs in memory.

Comment: Thanks. Can it be configured to show seconds as well?

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please explain the context in which you need seconds as well? Are you taking screenshots in rapid succession? If that's the case, you should be able to use the filename itself to contain the date (including seconds).  Keep in mind that the "modified" date will change if you edit the files! I routinely save my screenshots with `~/Pictures/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png` as the initial filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very personal choice (which file-manager/any-program best suits your tastes), but PCMan-FM (from LXDE) provides everything by default except seconds.

But do you need to change?

If you go to *File Manager Preferences* (Edit->Preferences) in Thunar then on the *Display* tab I can select DATE format from a pull-down list, my (x)Ubuntu 19.04 system has five (5) options which includes seconds (*let alone the Custom allowing you to set your own config if none of the 5 suit your needs*).

I also tested an 18.04 LTS box, and had the same 5 options, picture of the configuration window of `thunar` on my Xubuntu 18.04 LTS is

[image: Thunar File Manager Preferences window]

Comment: if you have access to different file managers could you please try, for example, `LANG=C dolphin` in a terminal (replacing `dolphin` with the relevant file manager's name)? When I open Dolphin using just `dolphin` in the terminal, I get `03/01/19 5:56 AM` but if I use `LANG=C dolphin`, I get `3 Jan 2019 05:56:07`. This maybe useful for file managers that don't offer an easy way to select date/time options.

Comment: @DKBose I noticed no difference in `pcmanfm` or `pcmanfm-qt`, nor `thunar` or `caja`.  I did however get the different date formats for `dolphin` that you described.

Comment: Thanks! It is just as you show for Thunar. I think I was too sleepy when I tried to solve it